# The row is larger than the container in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers

I have a problem with the use of Bootstrap.

The code is as follows:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Landing Page</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="bootstrap/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="main_header">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But the result is that the row is larger than the container.

I leave you a picture to understand what I mean

[image]

In custom.css there are only the height and the colors of the div.

Comment: I made this jsfiddle and it works well, or bad my example?
http://jsfiddle.net/GJS7c/

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969051/bootstrap-3-why-is-row-class-is-wider-than-its-container

Answer (score 7):

The row is not larger than the container. It is caused by the responsive design, which sets row `margin-left` to -30px on resolutions larger than 1200px. If you not want this, add

```
<style type="text/css">
.row {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
</style>
```

before `</head>`.

Other issues :

Your header should be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

You are using an oldschool HTML4 document definition. Use HTML5 (as bootstrap docs strongly recommend. With the above, your page will go in quirksmode in IE)

Also, use an updated **jquery**, your page will never work with 1.3 - "`on`" does not exists in 1.3, and bootstrap refers to jquery `on` many times. Use at least 1.7.1

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```