# Bootstrap 3 - Why is row class is wider than its container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just started using Bootstrap 3. I am having a difficult time 
understanding how the row class works.
Is there a way to avoid the `padding-left` and `padding-right`?

```
<div class="row" style="background:#000000">           
  <div class="col-xs-4 .col-xs-offset-1">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    col
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    col
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/petran/rdRpx/

Comment: @Adrift is this still true?

I'm not sure if you mean they don't work correctly, because I've been using them and they seem to work as they should.

Comment: @Cereal: Not anymore. This was [added](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/11050/files#diff-2) in v3.0.2

Comment: because bootstrap row has -15px left and right margins.

Comment: Probably not your problem but for anyone else having the same type of issue: Make sure you only have one class attribute on your divs. I accidentally doubled them up and got this same issue.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

In all grid systems, there are gutters between each column. Bootstrap's system sets a 15px padding on both the left and the right of each column to create this gutter.

The issue is that the first column should not have half a gutter on the left, and the last should not have half a gutter on the right. Rather than use some sort of `.first` or `.last` class on those columns as some grid systems do, they instead set the `.row` class to have negative margins that match the padding of the columns. This "pulls" the gutters off of the first and last columns, while at the same time making it wider.

The `.row` div should never really be used to hold anything other than grid columns. If it is, you will see the content shifted relative to any columns, as is evident in your fiddle.

UPDATE:

You modified your question after I answered, so here is the answer to the question you are now asking: Add the `.container` class to the first `<div>`. See [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/f7hb4dv3/1/).

Comment: Grid columns are separated by padding, not margin (in BS3)

Answer (score 31):

With bootstrap 3.3.7 this problem is solved wrapping the `.row` with `.container-fluid`.

Comment: this worked for me, even though initially I thought it didn't, that is because I had the developer's web console open which reduces the width, but apparently also messes this up. Using `.container-fluid` was also suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23616447/5272567

Comment: works, too, when the wrapping div is of position `absolute`. thanks for the hint

Comment: if I could up-vote this answer multiple times... :)

Comment: Same fix for Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 19):

See my reply below to similar post.

[Why does the bootstrap .row has a default margin-left of -30px?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21485438/2449290)

You basically use "clearfix" instead of "row". It does the exact same as "row" excluding the negative margin.

Comment: Those classes do two different things, though they may seem to visually do it.Clear isn't as flexible in responsive situations and with grid systems the behavior of .row is correct.

Comment: This solves overflowing content outside the wrapper.

Comment: But better way is to wrap row with container.

Comment: BEST ASWER! UP!

Answer (score 19):

I used the row class inside the container class and still had the some problem. When I added `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to the `.row` class it worked fine.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Adding the 'mx-auto' class in bootstrap 4 fixed the overflow issue for me.

Comment: Hey, it isn't recommended to change the margins on the bootstrap rows. 
They exist to cancel out the padding added by the .container or .container-fluid class.

Maybe in your case, your code might have any of the following issues: 

1. Someone removed default padding from the container which cancels outs the row's negative margin.
2. Or using box-sizing: "content-box" style is applied to the container. Make sure you have box-sizing: "border-box"

Answer (score 5):

@Michelle M. should receive full credit for this Answer.
She said in one of the Comments:

> Adding the 'mx-auto' class in bootstrap 4 fixed the overflow issue for
>   me.

You would need to update your first `div` Element like so:

```
<div class="row mx-auto" style="background:#000000">
```

No need to do this for all Nested-Rows (if you have them).
Just add `mx-auto` to the most-outer `row` (or Rows) to avoid the Vertical-Scrollbar.
Do not Override the behavior of all Bootstrap Rows by adding a "row" class to replace the Margins.

Answer (score 1):

For any future developers debugging this problem:

Bootstrap sets the padding for row columns, so none of the contents of a row should appear outside the container. If you're experiencing this and you are using bootstrap's grid system correctly using the col-... classes, it's likely that you have additional CSS somewhere resetting the padding on the columns.

Comment: Or, you have an old version of Bootstrap. For example, 3.0.0 distributed with VS2015. See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8959