# Twitter Bootstrap 3.0 row wider than window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I was fiddling around with Twitter Bootstrap and noticed that my `.row` was wider than the screen length.

Here is the [example](http://bootply.com/90307)

When bootstrap 3.0 came out I did not experience this.

The extra space on the right sides comes from `margin-right: -15px;`

I have been glaring at this for hours without making any progress on *why or how I am **fooling myself*** and searching has not been helpful.

I'm sure I am missing the obvious. I would like to understand why there is this space beyond the window width (forcing a scroller) and how to avoid it. I thought that a row would match 100%

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The correct solution (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-example-fluid) is to use the `container-fluid` class on the surrounding div:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea the bug can no longer be replicated and since the .container-fluid has been added. This is now the correct answer and so I have changed the accepted answer to yours. +1

Comment: This does **not** work if you put some columns inside. `bootstrap 3.2.0`, [Anes's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24028831/3744681) worked for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! It has taken me way to long to figure this out.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed it by just removing margin-left & margin-right from .row in bootstrap and also by setting it's width to 100%

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How does you answer improve upon the accepted answer?

Comment: The problem is that removing the margin left/right completely destroys one of the architectural cornerstones of bootstrap altogether....

Comment: The answer accepted didn't work. However, this seems to be the real answer.

Comment: Just setting the width to 100% worked for me. `bootstrap 3.2.0`, @JasonAller The accepted answer obviously doesn't work..., try with some columns inside..

Answer (score 7):

EDIT >>

This was the previously accepted answer. Undeleted if anyone sites with a old version.

EDIT <<

**It is a bug**

Which seems to have been unfixed for while. Maybe a proper fix in 3.1.

Best suggestion seems to be `"overflow-x: hidden` on `body` element.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10711

Other than that they added/clarified some of it in this [commit](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/f660bd42052949124a2c3342dadcdb12fd979f02)

Especially this line *"Folks looking to create fully fluid layouts (meaning your site stretches the entire width of the viewport) must wrap their grid content in a containing element with `padding: 0 15px;` to offset the `margin: 0 -15px;` used on `.row`"*

Answer (score 4):

Your rows need to be placed inside a div with the container class applied.

For example

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. As i understand it. The container's purpose is to center stuff. Without it i would have expected a row to be 100% width? Do i need to make a customer container?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by selecting a specific row, only one was expanding the width of the page, and removing the margins.

```
footer .row {
 margin-left: 0px !important;
 margin-right: 0px !important;
}
```