# why bootstrap's container class has padding while row class has negative margins to compensate the padding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap's `container` class has paddings on both side:

```
.container-fixed(@gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  padding-left:  (@gutter / 2);
  padding-right: (@gutter / 2);
}
```

While `row` class has negative `margins`:

```
.make-row(@gutter: @grid-gutter-width) {
  margin-left:  (@gutter / -2);
  margin-right: (@gutter / -2);
}
```

So when we put html like that:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

the content within the `row` class takes all the space from left to right side of the container offseting the `padding` using negaive `margins`. I'm wondering why this approach is used? I've also seen it being used for navbars, specifically `navbar-right` class has negative margin.

Comment: It's not regardless of padding - they are equal to each other and offset each other.  Not sure why it's used.

Comment: Yeah, right, offset each other. I rephrased it. However the question is why they do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap 3 - Why is row class is wider than its container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969051/bootstrap-3-why-is-row-class-is-wider-than-its-container) Also, this post explains more http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let me read it and maybe I'll consider closing the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting your columns in a .row offsets the padding, which is so you can nest columns. Nesting columns is important to have control of some (most) layouts. Since columns have built in padding, if you nest them without offsetting it that padding will multiply and column content won't line up like you want. See this example:

http://www.bootply.com/ZZ4ML0yjSG

```
<div class="container">
  <h3>Without .row buffer</h3>
  <div class="col-md-12 bg-warning">Column 1
    <div class="col-md-12 bg-danger">
      <div class="col-md-6 bg-info">Nested column 1 without .row buffer</div>
      <div class="col-md-6 bg-success">Nested column 2 without .row buffer</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <h3>With .row buffer</h3>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 bg-warning">Column 1
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 bg-danger">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 bg-info">Nested column 1 with .row buffer</div>
          <div class="col-md-6 bg-success">Nested column 2 with .row buffer</div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `.container` has padding to accommodate the negative margins of the `.row`, and the `.row` has negative margins because of the `col-*` (columns) work. Since columns use padding to create a gutter (space between columns), the row's negative margins eliminate the effect of the padding on the outermost columns.

Without the negative margin, there would be an extra 15 px on the outer sides as you can see here..

https://codeply.com/p/1bLNZAjk8D

Comment: Thanks. But if I set `padding: 0;` to `container` than everything is OK.

Comment: I guess the [article](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) **Dan** mentioned explains it - the padding on container and negative margin on rows are required to enable nesting of rows within columns.

Comment: If in your example I replace `<div class="col-lg-12"><div class="well"><p>12 wide</p></div></div>` with `<div class="col-lg-12"><div class="row"><div class="col-lg-8"><div class="well"><p>8 wide contains double gutter on the right</p></div></div></div></div>` I can see the double gutter on the right.