# Unwanted horizontal scroll bar using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a [website](http://libvmi.com/) using Bootstrap 3 (based off the [Carousel example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/)) that has an unwanted horizontal scroll bar in all of the browsers that I have checked (Chrome, Firefox, and Safari on Mac). All of the source for the website is [available online](https://github.com/libvmi/libvmi.github.io), but I'm guessing that I've done something wrong in my [custom CSS](https://github.com/libvmi/libvmi.github.io/blob/master/assets/css/libvmi.css). Any suggestions?

Comment: Would you like to put your answer below so I can mark this as answered?

Comment: Ok I will add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the jumbotron, the div with class `row` should be wrapped inside a div with class `container`. Horizontal scrollbar is because of the negative margins of the `row` class.

Class `row` has negative margins to it as the grid system has gutters between each columns. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969051/bootstrap-3-why-is-row-class-is-wider-than-its-container)

```
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```