# Bootstrap page body child rows are pushing beyond parent

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I understand the problem, as described and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18969051/bootstrap-3-why-is-row-class-is-wider-than-its-container).

I have quite a complicated layout with a sidebar navigation, a top navigation, a fluid-container and then page-title and page-body structure for each page. So just adding another container did not solve the problem as suggested in that answer.

Once I get into the page-body, all the rows are stretching 'outside' the parent page-body.

Notice I have added padding to the default container-fluid to 'pull' all the content in from each side of the page. Removing them does not fix it.

I've tried every change I can think of except removing the padding from the default row, because I'm pretty sure that is a no-no.

Anyone have any idea how to get those pesky form controls to stay 'inside' the page body?

Comment: there is two solution either give an additional class to row and manipulate its layout or don't use row use `<div class="col-md-*" />` without parent `.row` class div  as many times u want and use <div class="clearfix"> if you want to break forcefully to next row

Comment: @AtalKishore Thank you! I used the second method and removed the rows (and have not yet needed to forcefully break to a new row). I guess I was abusing the row class :)  Would you like to post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two solution either give an additional class to row and manipulate its layout or don't use `row` use `<div class="col-md-*" />` without parent .row class div as many times u want and use `<div class="clearfix">` if you want to break forcefully to next row

EDIT:-
For example

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">div1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">div2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">div3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">div4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">div5</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">div6</div>
</div>
```

**The same can be achieved  without `.row` class**

```
  <div class="col-md-4">div1</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">div2</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">div3</div>
  <div class="clearfix">div4</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">div5</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">div6</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">div1</div>
```